# Regex awk to Cisco Interface

Tags: awk, regular-expression, cisco, interface

I would like to know if have some Sed/Grep or Awk regex to parse Cisco interface section, with specific attribute, like bellow.

Content of file.txt

```
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip unreachables
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 no ip proxy-arp
!
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
VALUE="no ip proxy-arp"
awk -v RS='!\n' -v PATTERN=${VALUE} '/$PATTERN/' file.txt | awk '/^interface/';
exit 0
```

The problem is when I run line directly from shell, it work, but when I run from script, it don't work.

Running with `bash -x`, I can see that `awk` can't replace variable value.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Something like `grep -B1 'no ip proxy-arp' file.txt | head -1`? What is the expected output?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior I don't know whether this is necessary but the awk solutions deliver (possibly) more than one line. Thus the second part of the pipeline should be e.g. another grep.

Comment: FYI, you asked for `sed`|`grep`|`awk` assistance; however, [ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse) is a python module which specializes in handling these kind of tasks.  If you do a lot of this, it may be worth your while to consider using a library which is built for parsing cisco configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to believe that this works in your shell. Nonetheless this code contains several errors and also has the wrong approach IMHO.

awk expects a string between `//` not a variable. These are constant regular expressions. So you either make the shell put the variable there or you use `~`.

Your approach with corrections:

```
awk -v RS='!\n' -v PATTERN="${VALUE}" '$0 ~ PATTERN' file.txt | 
  awk '/^interface/'
```

I am surprised that this works. From the documentation I had expected that due to the setting of RS an unwanted "!" would be printed. However, I consider this one better:

```
awk -v PATTERN="${VALUE}" \
  '$0 ~ PATTERN { print previousline; }; { previousline=$0; }' file.txt
```

or with hardcoded pattern

```
awk '/no ip proxy-arp/ { print previousline; }; { previousline=$0; }' file.txt
```

or with the shell writing the pattern

```
awk /"$VALUE"/' { print previousline; }; { previousline=$0; }' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for `previousline`. Nice one :)

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip unreachables
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 no ip proxy-arp
"  | pcregrep -M "^interface .*0/1\n (.*\n)!"
```

result:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip unreachables
```

Comment: The OP only wants to show interfaces containing the text `no ip proxy-arp`, and your command doesn't check for that.  Your result only shows one section (the wrong one) because you've omitted the `!` from the end of the input.